# Native app crash in flutter. [FATAL:flutter/lib/ui/window/platform_message_response_dart_port.cc(53)] Check failed: did_send

Tags: android, flutter, crash

Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/lib/ui/window/platform_message_response_dart_port.cc(53)] Check failed: did_send.

This is happening while, I am downloading a pdf in flutter using dio package.